# Remove product from wishlist using customer id and product id in Magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, wishlist

How to remove product from wishlist using **customer id** and **product id** programmatically? I searched alot about it, But the results are remove wishlist item using **item id** only. So is there any way to remove wish list item using **customer id** and **product id** only?

Please suggest me how can I get this done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately Magento didn't provide ready to use function to delete item from wishlist. But you can use follow code to do this, I tested it and all works fine at my local Magento.

```
protected $wishlist;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist
) {
    $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
}

public function execute()
{
    $customerId = 1;
    $productId = 6;
    $wish = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
    $items = $wish->getItemCollection();

    /** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $item */
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) {
            $item->delete();
            $wish->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check this .....

Comment: this is now working

Answer (score 3):

The given answer is perfect here is my solutuion. Thank you so much @Amasty

```
protected $wishlist;

public function __construct(
      \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist
) {
      $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
}

    /* Remove a specific item from the wishlist.
     *
     * @api
     * @param  int $customerId id of customer.
     * @param  int $productId id of a product.
     * @return Empty wishlist.
     */
    public function removeWishlist($customerId,$productId) 
    {
        $wish = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
        $items = $wish->getItemCollection();
        foreach ($items as $item) 
        {
            if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) 
            {
                $item->delete();
                $wish->save();   
                return json_encode("You have successfully remove item from wishlist.");
            }
        }
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: not working here