# Magento 2.3 delete wishlist items not working

Tags: magento2, product, rest-api, wishlist

I am trying to delete wishlist items , using the below code but its not working, error is-

```
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store0` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id = main_table.product_id AND cat_index.category_id = '0' AND cat_index.visibility IN (3, 2, 4) WHERE (`wishlist_id` = '1') AND (`main_table`.`store_id` IN('0')) at /opt/lampp/htdocs/m233/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:110, PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'm233.catalog_category_product_index_store0' doesn't exist at /opt/lampp/htdocs/m233/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:91)"} []
```

I am calling "`removeWishlistForCustomer`" function using rest api.

```
<?php

/**
 * A Magento 2 module named Tvs/Wishlist
 *
 */

namespace Tvs\Wishlist\Model;

use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProvider;
use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory;
use Tvs\Wishlist\Api\WishlistManagementInterface;

/**
 * Defines the implementaiton class of the WishlistManagementInterface
 */
class WishlistManagement implements WishlistManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * @var WishlistProviderInterface
     */
    protected $wishlistProvider;
    private $wishlist;
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_wishlistCollectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var CustomerRegistry
     */
    protected $_wishlistFactory;
    /**
     *@var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    private $_objectManager;

    protected $_productload;
    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storemanagerinterface;
    protected $customerRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanagerinterface,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory $_wishlistCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist

    ) {
        $this->_objectManager             = $objectmanager;
        $this->wishlistProvider           = $wishlistProvider;
        $this->wishlist                   = $wishlist;
        $this->_productloader             = $_productloader;
        $this->_wishlistFactory           = $wishlistFactory;
        $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory = $_wishlistCollectionFactory;
        $this->storemanagerinterface      = $storemanagerinterface;
        $this->customerRegistry           = $customerRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer's name by Customer ID and return greeting message.
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException If customer with the specified ID does not exist.
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */

    public function addWishlistForCustomer($customerId, $productId)
    {

        if ($productId == null) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Invalid product, Please select a valid product'));
        }
        try {
            $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $product = null;
        }
        try {
            $wishlist = $this->_wishlistFactory->create();
            $wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId, true);
            $wishlist->addNewItem($productId);
            $wishlist->save();
            return 'Product with sku - ' . $product->getSku() . ' is added to wishlist';
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function getWishlistForCustomer($customerId)
    {
        if (empty($customerId) || !isset($customerId) || $customerId == "") {
            throw new InputException(__('Id required'));
        } else {

            $collection =
            $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId)->getData();
            $wishlistData = [];
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $productInfo = $this->_productloader->create()->load($item['product_id']);

                $data = [
                    "wishlist_item_id" => $item['wishlist_item_id'],
                    "wishlist_id"      => $item['wishlist_id'],
                    "product_id"       => $item['product_id'],
                    "store_id"         => $item['store_id'],
                    "added_at"         => $item['added_at'],
                    "description"      => $item['description'],
                    "qty"              => round($item['qty']),
                    "product"          => $productInfo,
                ];

                $wishlistData[] = $data;
            }
            return $wishlistData;
        }
    }

    public function removeWishlistForCustomer($customerId, $productId)
    {

        $wish  = $this->wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
        $items = $wish->getItemCollection();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) {
                $item->delete();
                $wish->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any opinions would be helpful.

Comment: You can refer this answer:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166027/remove-product-from-wishlist-using-customer-id-and-product-id-in-magento2 I hope this will help you.

Comment: I have tried that answer, its not working for me